How to fix Ambiguous use of error in Xcode Preview
I have this Color extension which overrides the default colors with my own versions
extension Color {
    static var black: Color { Color(rgb: 0x1D1D1D) }
    static var gray: Color { Color(rgb: 0x78859B) }
}


Text("Testing").foregroundColor(.black)

This builds and runs fine but when it comes to Xcode preview, I get "ambiguous use of 'black'" error. Why doesn't it work only on preview and how can I fix it without changing the my extension.
I'm using Xcode 15.4

Works for me on iOS 18, Xcode 16.

I didn't updated my mac yet so I couldn't install Xcode 16 :( I guess I should now
